# Is this video made from one coherent set of images or a mixture of several missions or even agencies?

Tags: rockets, history, space-art

**NOTE:** Looking at this 2+ years later, I realize now that a careful observer can likely answer this one fairly quickly. I'll do it myself eventually, but someone else is welcome to first.

---

In this video recognize what looks like a Project Echo reflective balloon, and what looks like the famous [Holmdel N.J. Microwave Horn antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holmdel_Horn_Antenna), but then there are one or more rockets shown, and several other tracking dishes.

Discounting the Project Echo stuff, are those two different rockets and just random dishes, or is there some coherence here?

(ignore the transoceanic cable and other underwater stuff).

[image]

**above:** screenshots from [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7bKe_Zgk4o) of Boards of Canada's "Music is Math.

**above:** [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7bKe_Zgk4o) of Boards of Canada's "Music is Math".

Comment: I suggest posting screen captures of the rockets you are asking about.  Many people will not want to watch a five minute video in order to answer your question.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've though of that so this is what I've done. The GIF is a hand-selected set of 22 screen captures, including clearly legible time codes so you can go directly to the video if necessary. If you start the YouTube viewer and then immediately hit pause, you can then click on the time bar and review still images without ever having to watch any video, or listen to it. Recent YouTube videos are completely Random Access Friendly.

Comment: Yeah.  That gif was giving me flicker epilepsy.