# What is this propeller-like object on top of the SpaceX Hopper?

Tags: spacex, identify-this-object

In the spirit of [Why does this rocket have a nose cone “cozy”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23923/12102) I'd like to ask why the SpaceX Hopper has a propellor on top, or at least something that looks reminiscent of [Beany's propeller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beany_and_Cecil).

What is this thing; what's it for, what does it do, how's it used exactly, etc.?

[image]

context:  [image: Beany and Cecil]

Comment: Look like a marine navigation radar but not understanding why it's there

Comment: Presumably this is part of range safety, I have read (citation needed) that operations are held or aborted if there are any marine craft down-range. Edit : considering marine craft, down-range would be towards the water. No point looking landward.

Comment: @BrianDrummond from this particular site, which direction is "down-range"? Don't they just hover and return to the ground? See the video in [Why did Starhopper's exhaust plume become brighter just before landing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38410/12102) My guess is that the radar will be used to check for *aircraft* when they start going for higher hops.

Comment: (edit aborted by 5 min cutoff) :  considering marine craft, down-range would be towards the water. No point looking landward. You probably want it to land on land, but during testing ya never know.

Comment: What's the difference between a 'propeller' and a 'propellor'? A propeller is a device that supplies impetus to move an object. A *propellor* is a device that *forces* an object into motion, with *severe penalties for non-compliance!* ;-)

Comment: @TomSpilker yes indeed, edited.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a radar intended to observe nearby boats.

Sources:

[tweet](https://twitter.com/nextspaceflight/status/1268699950210138112) by NASA Spaceflight Reporter Michael Baylor:

> SpaceX has asked the FCC for permission to operate a Garmin radar on top of a water tower in Boca Chica.
>
> The "water tower" looks familiar.

FCC filing: [Space Exploration Technologies Corp. 0459-EX-CN-2020](https://fcc.report/ELS/Space-Exploration-Technologies-Corp/0459-EX-CN-2020):

> ...**d) List any natural formations of existing man-made structures (hills, trees, water tanks, towers, etc.) which, in the opinion of the applicant, would tend to shield the antenna from aircraft:**
>
> This radar will be attached to the top of a water tower and is masked between 164 to 290 degrees to avoid illuminating launch or test vehicles. Please note that a TFR will be in place when the radar is operating.

Details of the application include a frequency range of 9300 to 9500 MHz, consistent with [Marine Radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_radar) in the [X-band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_band).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and *Welcome to Space!* Are you sure it will not also be used to look for nearby aircraft? It is a rocket after all ;-)

Comment: The application appears to be filled out dishonestly since the hopper is not a water tower, wonder why they didn't tell the truth?

Comment: from the application looks like https://buy.garmin.com/en-AU/AU/p/507697/pn/K10-00012-08 though all the models seem to use similar bases and antenna. The website claims it can be used to track weather and birds.

Comment: Thanks for the Welcome! Well, it used to be a rocket, but what is it now? ;-) Who knows whether they have filled it with water already... But I suspect they just made a joke in that application as many people initially thought SpaceX was having a water tower built which later turned out to be Hopper.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: What are you talking about? https://i.imgur.com/Hb3bDEA.png is clearly a water tower.

Comment: Maybe it's a water tower now?

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Notably the radar is absent from that photo...

Comment: @OrganicMarble my completely uneducated guess is that the published FCC regulations did not have a single applicable category for mostly static but occasionally hopping rockets that spend 99% of the time as fixed tall structures with attached active radars. There may have been a separate application for operating the radar while it is in flight, and it was agreed upon between SpaceX and the FCC ahead of time to use the existing water tower category in the regulations for operation while static.

Comment: @uhoh I had guessed similarly (except the radar is something recently added, long after its flying days were over). In structure and hazards, it's essentially identical to a water tower. For the purposes of the application, it's entirely reasonable to treat it as one, rather than going into a lengthy and quite irrelevant description of its origin and nature as an experimental rocket vehicle and how it can be treated in every way as if it were a water tower.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff ah, it's an ex-hopper now

Comment: I've just asked [What is "TFR" in the context of operating a marine radar on top of a "water tower" at a launch site?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44759/12102)