# What is "TFR" in the context of operating a marine radar on top of a "water tower" at a launch site?

Tags: launch, terminology, launch-site, radar, regulatory

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44747/12102) to *What is this propellor-like object on top of the SpaceX Hopper?* includes the following:

FCC filing: [Space Exploration Technologies Corp. 0459-EX-CN-2020](https://fcc.report/ELS/Space-Exploration-Technologies-Corp/0459-EX-CN-2020):

> ...**d) List any natural formations of existing man-made structures (hills, trees, water tanks, towers, etc.) which, in the opinion of the applicant, would tend to shield the antenna from aircraft:**
>
> This radar will be attached to the top of a water tower and is masked between 164 to 290 degrees to avoid illuminating launch or test vehicles. Please note that a TFR will be in place when the radar is operating.

**Question:** What exactly does "TFR" stand for in this context? How does one put one in place when a radar is operating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It stands for Temporary Flight Restriction.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_flight_restriction

Presumably the TFR is in place for whatever SpaceX is doing and the radar will be utilized during that same event. So the two things are associated, but one is not because of the other.

Comment: I think I see, the TFR tells aircraft to avoid flying in this area during "hopping tests" for example and they are just noting that these are the times that the radar will be transmitting. I'm guessing that the marine radar will come in handy detecting aircraft during the TFRs as well, thus [this less-than-completely-accurate comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44741/what-is-this-propellor-like-object-on-top-of-the-spacex-hopper#comment144751_44747).

Comment: Airplanes have no knowledge of and won't be disrupted by marine radars, they use different frequencies.

Comment: @GdD the radar will still readily *see* airplanes even though they aren't affected by it, right?

Comment: Generally not @uhoh, marine radars are design to look towards the horizon and to filter out fast moving objects, so it may see a helicopter hovering over the water but wouldn't see airplanes.

Comment: @GdD so the reflection is still there but the software may identify it as "too fast to be reasonably considered boat-like" and hide it from the user. A water plane landing would look like a boat suddenly appearing out of nowhere? And perhaps some have an option to turn this filter off?

Comment: @uhoh, it would have to be low to the surface to be seen as marine radars send out a narrow beam, I'm sure there are models which are configurable that way, or if you're SpaceX you'd just hack it.

Comment: Maybe this is too obvious, but perhaps they just wanted to look for boats before starting a test?  One of my friends who is vacationing down there just posted some pix of Boca Chica from a boat.

Comment: @GdD If I was me (and had an extra $10k) I'd hack it ;-) The wavelength is 3.3 cm and that thing isn't much taller than about 3 wavelengths, so it's *kinda* narrow-ish vertically but not terribly so. https://twitter.com/nextspaceflight/status/1268699950210138112/photo/2

Comment: I'm sure your local aviation authority would be happy about that @uhoh. They like that type of initiative...

Comment: @OrganicMarble if I were rocket hopping I'd wanna know what was in the air as well as what was in the water, but that's just me

Comment: @uhoh that's what the TFR is for.

Comment: @OrganicMarble we can tell the sheriff parked along the side of the road that they don't need their radar, because that's what speed limit signs are for, but I don't think they'll be convinced. TFR's don't *repel airplanes*

Comment: Notice that the application says as quoted in the question " masked between 164 to 290 degrees to avoid illuminating launch or test vehicles."  so it will only be looking out over the water.

Comment: @OrganicMarble ya I guess there's no way around that, until they change it

Answer (score 3):

A *TFR* is a *Temporary Flight Restriction*. My best guess for why SpaceX would include this information in their filing is that the FCC requires that marine radar does not interfere with airplane operations, and what SpaceX is saying is that because of the fact that there *are no* airplane operations when the radar is transmitting, there is no further need to demonstrate its safety.

Comment: If it's a standard commercial marine radar, then people use it all the time when airplanes are flying, is it the *height* that's different? Or has it been modified? Otherwise why mention this?